# What does this `…${…}…` code in the node docs mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, template-strings, template-literals

I am to trying to learn Express library and Node.js one step at a time. First I am looking at is the specifics of the Node `reqiure(moduleName)` function.

I took a look at [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) for this, and found some weird code in the example documentation:

```
const circle = require('./circle.js');
console.log( `The area of a circle of radius 4 is ${circle.area(4)}`);
```

More specifically the `${circle.area(4)}` bit.

From what I understand the `$` in JavaScript is just like any other variable. When we are using it on client side web development it is used as a delegate for the document function (I think). What is it assigned to when using node?

On top of that, what does this syntax mean? `${circle.area(4)}`

If `$` is just a reference to some function `someFunction()`, wouldn't it be equivalent to this `someFunction(){cirle.area(4)}`. I am not seeing how that could be valid syntax.

Also, why wouldn't they just directly call the `circle.area()` function directly anyways?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This:

```
`The area of a circle of radius 4 is ${circle.area(4)}`
```

is an example of [ES2015 template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

It interpolates whatever `circle.area(4)` represents directly into the string. If you're curious about this or other ES2015 features, I recommend checking out [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and playing around in the REPL.

[Here's a very simple example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=const%20foo%20%3D%20'some%20text'%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(%60%24%7Bfoo%7D%20is%20interpolated.%60)) to get you started.

You can see this ES2015 code:

```
const foo = 'some text';
console.log(`${foo} is interpolated.`);
```

is transpiled to its ES5 equivalent - a simple `+` concatenation:

```
var foo = 'some text';
console.log(foo + ' is interpolated.');
```