# What is meaning of $ in given code ${this.heroesUrl}/?id=${id}`

Tags: javascript

```
 const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/?id=${id}`;
```

What is the meaning of $ in given code.
i do not know how to use $ sign in hero service example in http service.
why use this $ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS and its use of Dollar Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648543/angularjs-and-its-use-of-dollar-variables)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678052/what-is-the-usage-of-the-backtick-symbol-in-javascript

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107981/what-does-this-code-in-the-node-docs-mean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this \`…${…}…\` code in the node docs mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107981/what-does-this-code-in-the-node-docs-mean)

Answer (score 3):

It is a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

> Template literals are enclosed by the back-tick
>   character instead of double or single quotes. Template literals can
>   contain placeholders. These are indicated by the dollar sign and curly
>   braces (`${expression}`).