# why ` is different than ' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

I started learning JavaScript, and I have faced this problem with strings.

the problem is

[image: ` is not ']

and the result is

[image: ` is not ']

Why are the results different?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. You clearly know how to type the two different quote marks, so what do you mean by "how can I write..."

Comment: Those are different characters and thus have different syntax meaning. Just like `=` is not the same as `!` so `\`` is not the same as `'`.

Comment: By using another key on your keyboard? I'm not sure to understand the question...

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/1260204 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/36107981/1260204 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/27678052/1260204

Comment: You can learn more about the differences on MDN, they are called [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`` - this is 'backtick' - when you use those characters, this is [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/template_strings). This syntax allows you, to use for example, multiline strings or nested js variables ${}.

'' or "" - this is standard js syntax for strings, you cannot use here ${}